# How to implement recursive put in sftp

Tags: recursion, sftp, put

Command-line sftp in my Ubuntu doesn't have recursive put implemented. I found some debate from 2004 about implementing such feature with -R option switch. So I see some sort of self-made recursion as only option.

Ie.

- iterate through directory listing
- cd into directories
- mkdir them if nonexistent
- put files

I'm planning on doing this with bash, but any other language would suffice.

Rsync or scp is not an option because I don't have shell access to server. Only sftp.

Comment: look at my answer for the solution using lftp

Comment: why is shell access necessary for scp?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look at [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html). It's a powerful file transfer client which supports ftp, ftps, http, https, hftp, fish (file transfer over ssh *shell*  session) and **sftp**. It has ftp-like interactive interface, but also allows to specify all commands at the command line. Look at `mput` (non recursive but handles glob patterns) and `mirror` (poor man's rsync) commands.

I use it with a server which only handles sftp uploads like this:

```
lftp -c "open -u $MYUSER,$MYPASSWORD sftp://$TARGET ; mirror -R $SOME_DIRECTORY"
```

Comment: Thanks, lftp seems to do the job. Luckily I don't have the same constraints I had back in '09 :)

Answer (score 4):

While I think lftp is the best option if it's available, I got stuck on an ancient install of Cent OS and needed to do a recursive put via SFTP only. Here's what I did:

```
find dir -type d -exec echo 'mkdir {}' \; | sftp user@host
find dir -type f -exec echo 'put {} {}' \; | sftp user@host
```

So basically make sure all the directories exist and then send the files over.

Answer (score 3):

my ubuntu 12.04 comes with `put -r` in sftp

Answer (score 2):

The GUI FTP client FileZilla also supports SFTP and also supports uploading and downloading while directories.

Answer (score 1):

On the command line you can do that by using the **putty-tools** package. 
It comes with a sftp replacement called `psftp`.

It supports `mput -r` which copies a local directory to the remote recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this with bash but it's going to be a lot of work. Instead, I suggest to have a look at [Python and the Chilkat library](http://www.example-code.com/python/sftp.asp).

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can use [edtFTPj/PRO](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpjssl/overview.html), our commercial product, to transfer recursively via SFTP. Alternatively you might want to consider SCP - that generally supports recursion and runs over SSH.

Answer (score 0):

How about [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html)?

Combined, of course, with `cp -r`.

Or, failing that, `rsync -r` by itself.

Comment: Quote from the question: "Rsync or scp is not an option because I don't have shell access to server. Only sftp."

Sshfs requires ssh access and I only have sftp.

Comment: Huh. I've never heard of having sftp access without ssh access, so I guess my brain ignored that part. You could still try sshfs. I don't actually know whether it works by ssh or sftp. If you're using GNOME or KDE, you can just type sftp paths into their respective file browsers.

Answer (score 0):

After lot's of googling and good answers I used Transmit syncing for the job. Not a very good solution, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how --

```
sftp -r  <host>
password:  <pass>

cd <remote dir>     # moves to remote dest dir

put -r localdir/*   # creates dir and copies files over
```